# Ссылка на файл не работает

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть ссылка для открытия файла и картинка, но они не работают, если по ним кликнуть, но если нажать открыть в новой вкладке, то необходимый файл открывается. Вот код html:

```
<div class="col-12 col-sm-4">
  <div class="home-hover navigation-slide">
    <a href="/files/111.pdf">
      <img src="images/PDF.png" style="width:20%">
    </a>
  </div>
  <a href="/files/111.pdf">
    <span style="color:white;">DOWNLOAD PDF</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Вот ошибки в консоли, которые появляются при клике на картинку:

```
script.js:187 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined
    at goToByScroll (script.js:187)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (script.js:206)
    at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:5)
    at HTMLDivElement.v.handle (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:5)
```

Вот код из скриптов, script.js:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    //Cache some variables
    var links = $('.nav').find('li');
    slide = $('.slide');
    button = $('.button');
    mywindow = $(window);
    htmlbody = $('html,body');

    //Create a function that will be passed a slide number and then will scroll to that slide using jquerys animate. The Jquery
    //easing plugin is also used, so we passed in the easing method of 'easeInOutQuint' which is available throught the plugin.
    function goToByScroll(dataslide) {
        var offset_top = ( dataslide == 1 ) ? '0px' : $('.slide[data-slide="' + dataslide + '"]').offset().top;

        htmlbody.stop(false, false).animate({
            scrollTop: offset_top
        }, 1500, 'easeInOutQuart');
    }

    //When the user clicks on the navigation links, get the data-slide attribute value of the link and pass that variable to the goToByScroll function
    links.click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        dataslide = $(this).attr('data-slide');
        goToByScroll(dataslide);
        $(".nav-collapse").collapse('hide');
    });

    //When the user clicks on the navigation links, get the data-slide attribute value of the link and pass that variable to the goToByScroll function
    $('.navigation-slide').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        dataslide = $(this).attr('data-slide');
        goToByScroll(dataslide);
        $(".nav-collapse").collapse('hide');
    });
});
```

Ошибка на строках:

```
        var offset_top = ( dataslide == 1 ) ? '0px' : $('.slide[data-slide="' + dataslide + '"]').offset().top;
и    
    goToByScroll(dataslide);
```

И ошибки в другом в файле в строках:

```
    while ((i = o.handlers[a++]) && !e.isImmediatePropagationStopped())(!e.namespace_re || e.namespace_re.test(i.namespace)) && (e.handleObj = i, e.data = i.data, r = ((x.event.special[i.origType] || {}).handle || i.handler).apply(o.elem, l), r !== t && (e.result = r) === !1 && (e.preventDefault(), e.stopPropagation()))
и
 return typeof x === i || e && x.event.triggered === e.type ? t : x.event.dispatch.apply(f.elem, arguments)
```

Comment: Никто не знает?

Comment: Обрабатывается клик по картинке, но не по тексту. При клике по картинке, получаете ошибку, так как свойства `.top` нету. Если нажимаете открыть в новой вкладке, обработка не запускается а просто открывается ссылка. Вопрос почему нет свойства `.top`?

Comment: @Максим т.е мне нужно добавить переменную top?

Comment: Нет. У вас селектор `$('.slide[data-slide="' + dataslide + '"]')` ничего не находит. Следовательно `offset()` вернет `undefined`.